# Netbeans GUI Builder Private Members

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, netbeans, builder

I have an existing project for which i have decided to create a GUI for in Netbeans. The problem I am encountering is the fact that every component that i drag-and-drop is private in the source and is unmodifiable. Must i create getters for everything?

I mainly just need this problem resolved for appending to the TextArea.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to change that globally, go to the options dialog, then select miscellaneous, and pick the gui builder tab. You can configure the default modifier there.

Answer (score 1):

By right clicking on a component in the `Inspector` panel, you can influence the generated code, even though it is in an *editor-fold* and not directly editable. For example, right click on a `JList` and edit the `Properties > model` to add text entries; right click on `Code > Post Creation Code` to add a code snippet affecting the selection model:

```
itemList.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);
```

Examine the code in the *editor-fold* to see the generated changes.

See also [*Introduction to GUI Building*](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/gui-functionality.html).

Answer (score 0):

You should see some tags in the code, something to do with begin and end of variable area. Usually there are 2 different sets of tags, any code between those tags will regenerate when you modify the gui with the form builder.

You can write your own code outside of those tags and it should remain even after you make changes. Getters and setters are a good idea if you need to update your object from another class. I've done that before with some text areas where I had a utility class update the text in it.

Comment: Ty for your help. I will go with getters and setters.

If anyone, in the future, wants to change the scope, Right-Click on customize the code on the component. Then, at the bottom of the popup change the access.